# Cyclic group of order 15 and cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G = <a>$ be a cyclic group of order 15, and $H = <a^{10}>$. List all the left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

I know that $<a> = \{a^0, a^1,...,a^{15}\}$. The problem doesn't say that $H$ is a cyclic subgroup so I'm if I assume that $H = <a^{10}> = \{a^{10}\}$.

A left co set would be say $x \in G, xH = \{xh: h \in H\}$ So then all of the left cosets would be $\{a^{15}\}, \{a^{16}\},...,\{a^{25}\}.$

I don't think this is correct but my book doesn't really give any details aside from the definition of a cyclic group. Any help in solving this or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: $H$ is cyclic.  The notation $\langle a^{10}\rangle$ means the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a^{10}$.  Since, $H$ is generated by a single element, it is cyclic.  Also, note that $a^{16}=a\cdot a^{15}=a\cdot e =a$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski so then it would have infinite order? So then all the cosets would be for example $\{ a^{10}, a^{20}, a^{30},...\},\{ a^{11}, a^{21}, a^{31},...\},... ,\{ a^{35}, a^{45}, a^{55},...\}$?

Comment: G contains only {e, a, a^1, a^2...a^14} so each coset contains only elements from there.

Comment: We do not write $a^{15}$ in this case, since $a^{15} = e$ and similarly $a=a^{16}=a^{31}=a^{46}=\dots$.  Instead of ever writing something with an exponent larger than $14$ or smaller than $0$, we instead write it with an exponent between $0$ and $14$ (inclusive).  Think of it this way, if I have the multiplicative group generated by $-1$, so I have $(-1), (-1)^2, (-1)^3, (-1)^4, (-1)^5,\dots$, If I were to instead evaluate each, the previous list is simply $-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1,\dots$.  Rewriting the same element multiple times (although the representation is different) is redundant.

Comment: Ok so it's like in modular arithmetic. I understand this idea, but if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then how is it that $H = \{e, a^5, a^{10}\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a similar solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499366/finding-cosets-and-index-in-d8/1499422#1499422).

For brevity, I'll just give a general idea: first, you should determine the exact contents of H. You can do this just by repeatedly exponentiating a<sup>10</sup> until you get e. You should see that H={a<sup>10</sup>, a<sup>5</sup>, e}.

Then, you go through elements of G and find what coset they produce. You already know that a<sup>10</sup>, a<sup>5</sup>, and e are in < a<sup>10</sup>>. You should look at elements that you haven't yet seen in a coset, and see what you get. For example, a*< a<sup>10</sup>>={a<sup>11</sup>, a<sup>6</sup>, a}. Just keep repeating until every element has been put in a coset. Note that cosets partition the group, so you should see each element once and only once, and that each coset should be the same size- that of the subgroup, so here 3- so you should get 5 cosets total since there are 15 elements in the whole group.

Comment: I'm still working on that problem based on your advice. But $a^{10}$ is the generator of the group, so how would we get $a^5$? Also if $H$ is cyclic then wouldn't $H = \{a^{10}, a^{20},...\}$? I thought that was the definition of a cyclic group.

Comment: @Nid $a^{10}\cdot a^{10} = a^{20} = a^{15}\cdot a^5 = e\cdot a^5 = a^5$.  Note that since our original group is of order $15$, any element raised to the fifteenth power will be the identity.

Comment: H is cyclic, but as a supgroup of G=<a^15>. Try to think of it as the group of integers modulo 15. You have the elements 0, 1, up to 14. When you add those integers, you take the sum mod 15 to ensure that you get a group element. Similarly, a^10 * a^10 = a^5 since 10+10=5 (mod 15).

Comment: Now I'm confused. I understand why what you said is true. My understanding of the definitions is lacking. So $<a> = \{ a^0, a^1,..., a^{15}\}$. I get that. So then how is $<a^{10}> = \{a^{10}, a{5}, e\}$? The problem didn't give any details about $H$. Secondly, I thought that in cosets you take an element of a group and multiply it with every element of the given subgroup to achieve the set. So then how did we get that $a^{20} = a^5$? unless its a composition? I apologize my book and instructor are terrible this semester. I'm trying to research these topics on my own.

Comment: Ok. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ that makes sense. It wasn't explicitly said. so I assumed otherwise. But I still don't under stand how $a^{10}$ generates ${e, a^5}$.

Comment: @Nid First, a^15=e in G, something I'll explain later. The cyclic group H=<a^10> is the subgroup of G where each element is an exponent of a^10, which is referred to as the generator. We know that G is cyclic, and that a generates G. Since G has order 15, we know that |a|=15, so a^15=e.To find <a^10>, we start with a^10 since it is itself raised to the power 1, then keep multiplying it by itself until we get e. a^10*a^10 = a^20. However, since a^15=e, this simplifies to e*a^5=a^5.

Comment: I get why $a^{10} = a^{10}$ and $a^{20} = a^5$ and $a^{30} = e$. It's just like modular arithmetic. That makes perfect sense. I just didn't realize $H$ was necessarily a subgroup of $G$ and would have to follow the same rules. Thank You all for the help. That makes a lot more sense.